# x86 assembly addition big numbers with carry

Tags: assembly, x86, addition

Adding two big numbers (128bit).

```
SYSEXIT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

.data
number1:
    .long 0x10304008, 0x701100FF, 0x45100020, 0x08570030
number2:
    .long 0xF040500C, 0x00220026, 0x321000CB, 0x04520031

.text
.global _start
_start:


addition:
    movl $4, %ecx
    clc
add_loop:
    movl %ecx, %edx
    decl %edx
    movl number1(,%edx,4), %eax
    movl number2(,%edx,4), %ebx
    adcl %eax, %ebx
    pushl %ebx
    loop add_loop


mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
mov $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
int $0x80
```

I check it under gdb using `x/5wx $esp` and I have always `00000001` in the beginning as 5th word, even if I change number2 for `0x1040500C, 0x00220026, 0x321000CB, 0x04520031` to prevent carry.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You only store 4 words, so why do you expect the 5th one to have any specific value?

By the way, that `1` should be the number of arguments passed to your program, where the first argument is customarily the name of the program itself.

Comment: I can't change numbers at all by adding 0x00000000 in the beginning of each one ( I'm not sure if I understand You well ). I have to check result only from esp either. No ideas.

Comment: He means you're only pushing 4 numbers onto that stack. The fifth number, the `00000001`, was already there, before your `_start` function was called. You don't attempt to push a number representing the carry bit onto the stack, so naturally, you never see it when you look.

Comment: Is there any other way to show overflow? Or do I only have to write `x/4wx $esp` and then  `info registers eflags` to check if CF is set?

Comment: No, it's not a coincidence - "that `1` should be the number of arguments passed to your program". Arguments to `_start` get passed on the stack. You can use `setc` to set a register or memory location to the value of your carry flag, and then push that or examine it directly, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

As Jester mentions in his answer, you're not attempting to push the value of the carry bit onto the stack, so you're not seeing it - set or otherwise - when you look for it. That `00000001` was put there before `_start` was called.

You can use `setc` to set a register or memory location to the value of the carry flag, and push that, if you want to. Here's an example, with a few changes made for 64 bit assembly:

```
SYSEXIT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

        .global _start

        .section .data
number1:  .long 0x10304008, 0x701100FF, 0x45100020, 0x08570030
number2:  .long 0xF040500C, 0x00220026, 0x321000CB, 0x04520031
carryval: .long 0x00

        .section .text
_start:
        movl    $4, %ecx
        clc

add_loop:
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        decl    %edx
        movl    number1(,%edx,4), %eax
        movl    number2(,%edx,4), %ebx
        adcl    %eax, %ebx
        setc    carryval                #  Added this line
        push    %rbx                    #  Changed for 64 bit
        loop    add_loop

        movl    carryval, %eax          #  Added this line
        push    %rax                    #  Added this line

        mov     $SYSEXIT, %eax
        mov     $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
        int     $0x80
```

with gdb output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/asm$ gdb ./bigint
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/paul/src/asm/bigint...done.
(gdb) b 29
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000df: file bigint.s, line 29.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/paul/src/asm/bigint 

Breakpoint 1, add_loop () at bigint.s:29
29          mov     $SYSEXIT, %eax
(gdb) x/5xg $rsp
0x7fffffffe518: 0x0000000000000001  0x0000000000709014
0x7fffffffe528: 0x0000000070330125  0x00000000772000eb
0x7fffffffe538: 0x000000000ca90061
(gdb)
```

and you can see that the topmost value is now set to `1`, to indicate your carry bit was set.

If you change the first double word of `number2` to `0x1040500C`, then you'll get this:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/asm$ gdb ./bigint
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/paul/src/asm/bigint...done.
(gdb) b 29
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000df: file bigint.s, line 29.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/paul/src/asm/bigint 

Breakpoint 1, add_loop () at bigint.s:29
29          mov     $SYSEXIT, %eax
(gdb) x/5xg $rsp
0x7fffffffe518: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000020709014
0x7fffffffe528: 0x0000000070330125  0x00000000772000eb
0x7fffffffe538: 0x000000000ca90061
(gdb)
```

showing your carry flag was *not* set, as expected.